# Why "alignas" specifier cannot align two byte buffer strictly by 1 byte boundary?

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment

Can anyone explain me why using specifier `alignas` it is not possible to create buffer on stack which contains 2 bytes and aligned strictly by specified alignment(not more and not less)?

To be clear what I mean here is code snippet:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    // create buffer on stack which contains 2 bytes and aligned by boundary of 1 byte
    alignas(1) std::byte buf[2]{};

    // convert pointer to first byte in the buffer to unsigned integer
    const auto buf_ptr_as_uint = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(buf);

    // expect that address of first byte in the buf aligned by boundary of 1 byte(not 2)
    // namely I expect that last bit of buf_ptr_as_uint should be equal to 1
    // but this is not true. assert is always being triggered.
    assert((buf_ptr_as_uint & 1));
}
```

I understand that any address which is aligned by boundary of 2 bytes is already aligned by boundary of 1 byte. But even so I was expecting that "alignas" should align my buffer exactly according to the specified alignment especially considering that requirement for alignment of `std::byte` should allow to satisfy my will to align `buf` strictly by 1 byte boundary.

So my question is: why `alignas` works in this way? And is there a way to force compiler to align my buffer strictly by specified alignment(besides allocating bigger buffer and skipping bytes inside it)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `alignas(1)` does not require an address to be odd. 0x1000 and 0x1001 are both well aligned as 1 byte. Moreover, the aligned address is relative to other addresses, if a function stack frame starts with 0x1000 why do you expect the address of `buf` to be 0x1001?

Comment: @273K apparently I did not fully understand the meaning of `alignas`. But thank you for clarification with a well chosen example. This really helped me.

Comment: Try to experiment with bigger align values, it's more useful. For example you might want `alignas(16) std::byte buf[32]{};` for accessing `long double` in a byte array.

Comment: If you want to force misalignment, you can put the buffer inside a larger aligned structure, and put a member in front of the buffer that forces the buffer to be misaligned. `alignas(2) struct container { std::byte misaligner; std::byte buf[2]{}; };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alignas` only specifies that the object's address must be aligned *at least as strict* as it specifies.

> why alignas works in this way?

Because the point of `alignas` is to make sure that the buffer/storage is usable to place objects there which have certain alignment requirements. For that it doesn't matter whether the buffer is *also* aligned for other types with higher alignment requirement (and even if it did, usually you'd want to have your memory be aligned for *more*, not *less*, types).

What is the point of intentionally misaligning for types that have a higher alignment requirement as stated in the `alignas` specifier and likely forcing the compiler to waste space in the process? I do not see any use case.

> And is there a way to force compiler to align my buffer strictly by specified alignment(besides allocating bigger buffer and skipping bytes inside it)?

There isn't. What you suggest is the way to do it. The compiler couldn't implement it any other way either.

Comment: The point of intentionally misaligning for types that have a higher alignment requirement than stated in the `alignas` specifier is for writing unit tests for buffers with different alignment.

Comment: @dummy In that case I would do what you suggested, but varying the offset into the buffer to catch misaligned subobjects.

Comment: yes for this moment this is the only viable way I can see to accomplish my task. Thanks